# which one : A or An European?

Tags: capitalization

It seems like "A European" is the correct one but why ?

Is this a general rule about Capitalized words?

Comment: a duplicate of what? please leave a link back to the best source of information...

Answer (score 8):

Even though *European* begins with a letter that often represents a vowel sound, phonetically it begins with the consonant /j/. That is why it is preceded by *a* and not *an*. The capital letter is irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

Any word that sounds like it begins with a consonant is preceeded by the pronoun A, even if it begins with the letter E. Since the word EUROPEAN sounds like it begins with a Y, the proper pronoun is A.

If the stress does not fall on the first syllable, then an rather than a is used.

a h **i** story of England.

an hist **o** rical timeline.

a **eur** opean of note

Comment: is this really important ? can we say whichever we want ?

Comment: I can't agree with the second example. I certainly just say 'a historial...'

Comment: @CatwithaFez, It is quite important though. Try saying a few phrases that should have "an" with "a". It *feels* uncomfortable with the stop. `a owl`, `a apple`, `a umbrella`, `a editor`, `a ice-cream`

Comment: If the stress does not fall on the first syllable ***and*** the first consonant in the word is 'h' ***and*** you are one of the minority of English speakers who speaks this way, you may use 'an'.  It's "a min **or** ity", "a Eu **clid** ean space".  but "a/an hist **or** ical".

Comment: *A* is not a pronoun. −1 for that alone.